# Javascript ternary produces unexpected result with React state, when compared to the if else counterpart

Tags: javascript, reactjs

EDIT: I don't know if it's a compiler hiccup or some implementation defined behavior... It fixed itself while I was working on another component... I did not make this up and I'm quite baffled as well.

So I'm writing a toggle className based on the state of the component. But it keeps producing the wrong result. Therefore, I tried to do a little test and compare the ternary statement with if and else. Here's my test

```
const var1 = `valA ${this.state.someProperty === true ? "valB" : ""}`
var var2
if(this.state.someProperty === true){
    console.log("true")
    var2 = "valA valB"
}
else{
    console.log("false")
    var2 = "valB"
}
console.log(var1)
console.log(var2)
```

When run, it logs

```
true
valA
valA valB
```

I tried to put this code into a code snippet, and replace the state with `true` and they produce the expected result (var1 == var2).
The state is set to true in the constructor. I removed all code that changes it. I tried to log it too and it's `true`.
But even if the state is changed somehow, shouldn't var1 and var2 produce the same result?

I tried to replace the state with `true` in my development code, and it worked as expected.
But I'm not sure what in the comparison is throwing it off. I tried

```
`valA ${this.state.someProperty ? "valB" : ""}
```

```
`valA ${this.state.someProperty == true ? "valB" : ""}
```

```
`valA ${this.state.someProperty === true ? "valB" : ""}
```

and they all fail for some reason

Comment: can you please post your source code for this?

Comment: The code here should work fine. I have the feelings it's something connected to the state not the function. Can you show your whole component, or the part responsible for this.

Comment: I really don't know what's wrong. It's working after like 30 mins. I'm quite baffled myself

Comment: probably hot reload took some time to update (or needed a refresh so that previous state doesn't persist), or something in your pipeline hiccuped.  has happened to me a lot.  I normally notice it quickly enough while debugging though

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
this.state.someProperty ? 'valA valB' : 'valA'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my bug kind of fixed itself. I don't know what happened and I'm quite confused as well,  but at least it's working.